# Why does Spring Boot crash with an imported certificate key but not a generated one?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have a Spring Boot api that I want to use SSL.  For testing the setup, I created a keystore in keytool with a generated RSA key.  The api boots fine.  However, when switching to the main keystore which contains a .crt certificate imported with keytool, the api crashes with the following error: Alias Name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry.  However 'tomcat' is a valid alias in the keystore in keytool -list, and the certificate itself is valid.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference - the keystore and cert were valid.  Just make sure the cert and private key are bundled beforehand using a tool such as openssl. worked like a charm after importing that .p12